# Getting Single Value from my ObservableList

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx-2, observablelist

```
    chkbrg.setOnAction(e -> {list.getItems().add("Chicken Burger         "+ chkbrgval); 
        total += chkbrgval;
        ioi.setText(""+"$" +total);
        });

    ListView<String> list = new ListView<>();
    ObservableList<String> non;
    non=list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();    

    for(String m:non){
        list.getItems().remove(m);
        System.out.println(m);
    }
```

Hello, I just want to know how I can I get the variable value from this ObservableList as adding them is easy with this CODE but i am unable to subtract them back from the "total" variable. How can i know what Variable is selected in 'm' and how can i subtract that value.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

`SelectionModel` should have method **getSelectedIndices** (`list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices()`) which return element indexes.  You can use them to remove elements by their position/indexes.